# Deprecated: preg_replace(): How to convert to preg_replace_callback?

Tags: php

How can I convert the following preg_replace to preg_replace_callback?

```
            $this->template = preg_replace ( "#\\[group=(.+?)\\](.*?)\\[/group\\]#ies", 
 "\$this->check_group('\\1', '\\2')", $this->template );
```

What I've tried:

```
        $this->template = preg_replace_callback( "#\\[not-group=(.+?)\\](.*?)\\[/not-group\\]#ies",
                function($this) {
                        return $this->check_group($this[1], $this[2], false);
                }
        , $this->template );
```

and the above preg_replace_callback gives me an empty result.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use the \e modifier in your preg_replace_callback() call or php will throw the following warning and return nothing:

> PHP Warning:  preg_replace_callback(): Modifier /e cannot be used with
>   replacement callback in /wherever/you/used/it.php on line xx

also, just a suggestion, don't use $this as your argument name in your callback function... that is just confusing.

Answer (score 2):

In order to properly use '$this' in context you need to provide the use keyword for the anonymous function.  Besides, $this is a special variable and its bad practice to use it directly as a function parameter.  Also in your anonymous function, you're attempting to use $this as a variable for your matches, and I would replace $this in the function parameter with a more descriptive variable '$matches'.  See if the following solves your problem.

```
    $this->template = preg_replace_callback( "#\\[not-group=(.+?)\\](.*?)\\[/not-group\\]#is",
            function($match) use ($this) {
                    return $this->check_group($match[1], $match[2], false);
            }
    , $this->template );
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you are missing a semicolon **`;`**  there

```
return $this->check_group($this[1], $this[2], false);
                                             -------^ // Here
```

Comment: Can you update a test data and your expected output in the question ?

Comment: it seems that in php5.5 you can't use the e modifier. changed `#ies` to `#isu` and it's working now